Find the measure of $\measuredangle BAC$ in the triangle below given two sides and an angle
Em um triângulo $ABC$, se $∡⁢⁢=34^⁢30′$; $AB = 6$ e $BC = 10$.
Calcular ∡⁢⁢.
(Answer:$71^o 30'$)

I try:
T.coss: $6^2 = 10^2+AC^2-2.6.AC.cos \angle C \implies 12AC cos \angle C C$
$\therefore cos \angle C = \frac{64 - AC^2}{12AC}$
$AC^2 = 6^2+10^2-2.6.10.cos \angle = 136-120cos \angle  B$
$\therefore cos \angle B =\frac{136-AC^2}{120}$
How to finish without using a calculator for the cosine values?

I got $\angle BAC \approx 70.7^\circ$ or its supplement using the sine law.

As it is a Peruvian exercise, they use many approximations, so I would like to find the geometric resolution without a calculator

Then what is the acceptable error from $70.7^\circ$?

"How to finish without using a calculator for the cosine values?" Why do you think you can?

@fleablood  Because it is taken from a Peruvian geometry book where a calculator is not used in the resolutions

@peterwhy Therefore, if there is a geometric resolution, it would be possible to see how this approximation was made.

I would use the "sine rule:
$\frac{sin(34.5)}{6}= \frac{sin(A)}{10}=
 \frac{sin(B)}{b}$.
$sin(A)= (10/6) sin(34.5)= (5/3)(0.5664)= 0.994$
$A= arcsin(O.994)= 70.7$ degrees.
70.7=

And how would you do the calculation without a calculator?

Do you realise your angle might not be unique?
I've drawn a line segment with a length of $10$, an angle of $34.5°$ on it, and then I drew a circle with a radius of $6$, and this is what I came up with:

Apperently, there might be two solutions to your problem.

AB= 6 and not 10. Even if we change AB to BC in your figure there will be no possibility of having two values

@petaarantes Yes, there are.

$\mathsf{BF \perp AC (F \in AC)\\
\triangle BFC: BC^2 = 9l^2+13l^2 = 250l^2 \therefore BC = 5\sqrt{10}l
\therefore 5\sqrt{10}l = 10 \implies l = \frac{\sqrt{10}}{5}\\
BF = 9l = \frac{9\sqrt{10}}{5}\\
\triangle ABF: 6^2 = (\frac{9\sqrt{10}}{5})^2+AF^2 \implies AF = \frac{3\sqrt{10}}{3}\\
\therefore \triangle ABF:(a:3a:a\sqrt{10}) \implies (\frac{37^o}{2}:\frac{153^o}{2}:90^o)\\
\therefore \angle B = \frac{111^o}{2}+\frac{37^o}{2} = 74^o \\
\angle BAC = 180^o-74^o - 34,5^o = 71,5^o  = \boxed{71^o 30'}
}$



And how would you do the calculations without a calculator? $$\begin{align*}
\tan34.5^\circ &\overset?= \frac9{13}\
\cos \frac{37^\circ}{2} &\overset?= \frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}
\end{align*}$$
Still not yet explained by double angle formulae:
$$\begin{align*}
\tan 69^\circ &\overset?= \frac{2\cdot 9/13}{1-(9/13)^2} = \frac{117}{44}\
\cos 37^\circ &\overset?= 2\cdot\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}\right)^2-1 = \frac45
\end{align*}$$
